# Angular 4 give error as "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute"

Tags: ionic2, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

I am developing mobile application in ionic 2 with angular 4. I have implemented login page with reactive form previously it is working correctly but while implementing feature as after logout control will redirect to login page. So, I have created sharedModule which I have imported in my app.module.ts file. After this I am getting an below error:

No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

```js
Login.ts
   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
                private auth: AuthServiceProvider, private alertCtrl: AlertController,
                private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public storage: Storage,
                private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
            'dashboardUsername': [null, Validators.required],
            'dashboardPassword': [null, Validators.required]
        })
    }
```

```html
 Login.html
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
     <ion-row class="htm-container">
      <ion-col>
      <ion-list inset>
      <ion-item class="inputRounded"                                            [class.error]="!loginForm.controls['dashboardUsername'].valid && loginForm.controls['dashboardUsername'].touched">
     <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Dashboard username"                             [formControl]="loginForm.controls['dashboardUsername']" name="dashboardUsername"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="htm-error"                         *ngIf="loginForm.controls['dashboardUsername'].hasError('required') && loginForm.controls['dashboardUsername'].touched">
    <p>Username is required!</p>
     </div>
     <ion-item class="inputRounded"                        [class.error]="!loginForm.controls['dashboardPassword'].valid && loginForm.controls['dashboardPassword'].touched">
     <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Dashboard password" 
        [formControl]="loginForm.controls['dashboardPassword']" name="dashboardPassword"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
      <div class="htm-error" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['dashboardPassword'].hasError('required') &&
                      loginForm.controls['dashboardPassword'].touched">
    <p>Password is required!</p>
     </div>
     </ion-list>
      </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
     <ion-col class="signup-col">
     <button ion-button color="light" class="submit-btn btn-bottom-margin" full type="submit"
       [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Sign In
     </button>
     </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Third party controls such as yours require ControlValueAccessor to function with angular forms otherwise they behave like native elements and can use DefaultValueAccessor. in such cases you should use `ngDefaultControl` attribute.
In your case

```
<ion-input type="text" placeholder="Dashboard username"
 ngDefaultControl
[formControl]="loginForm.controls['dashboardUsername']" name="dashboardUsername">
```

Should fix that for you.

Comment: thanks, this error also appear in *Ionic 4 with Angular* when we want to make tests.

Comment: @DrutaRuslan you are right, but do you know why we need this in tests but not in the real build? im confused about this behavior

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use formControl and name at same time. 
If you want a name attribute than you may write as:

```
<ion-input type="password" placeholder="Dashboard password" 
    [formControl]="loginForm.controls['dashboardPassword']" [attr.name]="dashboardPassword"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your solution and also tried with removing name attribute but still getting same error.